# Non Blocking File Upload in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, nonblocking

I have a button which when clicked opens up an overlay which is a form in an iframe. There is a file upload, I succeeded in making the overlay disappear and redirect the parent window to another page on submit. The problem is here:

If the user uploads a huge file the file has to be uploaded first before the user is redirected. Is there another way where the file is uploaded and at the same time the overlay is closed and the parent window redirected without loosing the file upload?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Have you tried using something like Uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) ? This handles that logic quite nicely

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution is quite simple. Don't use an iframe for the file upload. Just put your form with the file upload dialog into the main page. If the upload is finished the server can send a redirect back to the client and then the user is redirected to the new site.
Or is there any problem with such simple solution?

**UPDATE**
Because the simple solution doesn't work I suggest another solution. Add an onload event listener to the iframe. If the event handler of the onload event is called (that means the file upload is finished) then redirect the user. To redirect the user you can use `window.location.href = "your new url";` But be aware that you add the event listener after the file form of the iframe is completely loaded or you have to ignore the first fired event (which would be the loaded file form) in you event handler.

Comment: Hi yes there is a problem, the structure of the site was already done by developers and the client agreed on having an overlay I cannot change any of the structure. So basically i am stuck with the iframe in an overlay situation and cannot change it. What I read was that node.js would help me but I am finding it very difficult to install it and understand the notion of node.js any experience?

Comment: I don't think you are understanding my situation. I have this scenario A retailer can add brochures or shops to the system. He clicks on add a brochure and an overlay an iframe which contains a form to create the new brochure. 

The retailer chooses which pdf/brochure he wants to upload from his computer, inserts the name etc and presses submit. Currently the iframe waits for the pdf to be uploaded than it hides the overlay and redirects the retailer to the brochures page to show him the newly created brochure.

Comment: What I need is that when he presses submit the overlay is hidden immediately and the user is redirected to the brochures page whilst at the same time the brochure he uploaded is being uploaded in the background. The user can navigate through the different parts of the site or even leave the site whilst the brochure he uploaded is being uploaded in the background server side, that's why I thought node.js would come in. 

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you use AJAX for the navigation of your site, the file upload can run in the background and the user can navigate normally on the website. If you don't use AJAX for the whole site then it's not possible. If you have one <a href="..."> in your code and the user clicks it then the file upload will be canceled because the iframe will be "deleted".

Answer (score 0):

just try this ...

1. when the form submission is completed(means file uploaded) in server side you need to set a session flag like $_SESSION['file_uploaded'] = TRUE;

Before the step1 in parent window you need to write an ajax function to check the session. That js ajax function continuously contact the server after the overlay(iframe) loaded.
when the server returns true you can hide the overlay and then redirect the page to some other location.

Comment: The problem is that the user has to be redirected immediately on pressing submit and not when the file is uploaded. 

So basically he fills in the form and chooses the file to upload and then presses submit and unless there are problems with validation it will close the overlay and redirect the parent page to the home screen. Whilst at the same time the pdf is still being uploaded in the background

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I use either Valum's plugin or [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started).

If you insist on iframe file upload, see older version of [Valum's AJAX file upload](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload). Either use his package, or see the code for inspiration. Don't get confused by the name; it doesn't use AJAX but iframe for file uploading.

Note that the [newer version of Valum's plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) probably  uses AJAX also.